# Robot Framework- I Rename the Project name and directory name , after that, getting invalid error in python interpreter

Tags: selenium, robotframework

Steps followed by me-
In Pycharm I created a project ENT and developed a robot framework for my Application- It already has many test cases
Now because of some requirement, I had to change the name of the project.
So i refactor the project name by right click on the project and also I went to the directory and rename the folder from ENT to ENT_Admin.

Now I am getting error in all the keywords. when I went to file -- setting- project --python interpreter, i am getting error there.

invalid python 3.9 ENT.

please help me with the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try some solution from [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add-existing-interpreter)

> **Modify a Python interpreter﻿**
>
> 1. Press Ctrl+Alt+S to open IDE settings and select Project  | Python Interpreter.
> 2. Expand the list of the available interpreters and click the Show All link. Alternatively, click the (cogwheel icon) and select Show
>    All.
> 3. Select the target interpreter and click Edit.
>
> You can specify an alternative interpreter name for the selected
> interpreter. The Python interpreter name specified in the Name field,
> becomes visible in the list of available interpreters. Click OK to
> apply the changes.
>
> For remote interpreters (that are available in PyCharm Professional)
> you can modify configuration parameters.

If this doesn't help try to create a new project and import your already renamed project. If your project contains some hidden folder like ".idea" delete it before importing.